# Get Real Solutions works in Solve but PositiveReals don't (Quantities)

Tags: equation-solving, assumptions, units

I'm trying to get the R+ Solutions to a school problem with solve. Everything works fine with `Dom -> Reals` but when I try `Dom -> PositiveReals` it throws no solutions even if they exists.

```
(* Data *)

epsilon = 0.3;
Tinf = Quantity[295.15, "Kelvins"];
Q = Quantity[5000, "Watts"/"Meters"^2];
h = Quantity[10, "Watts"/("Meters"^2*"Kelvins")];
sigma = Quantity[5*10^-8, "Watts"/("Meters"^2*"Kelvins"^4)];

(* Equations *)

Qconv[T_] := h (T - Tinf)
Qrad[T_] := sigma*epsilon*(T^4 - Tinf^4)
Solve[Q == Qconv[T] + Qrad[T], T, Reals]
```

Executing this code throws

```
{{T -> Quantity[-1055.54, "Kelvins"]}, {T -> Quantity[605.245, "Kelvins"]}}
```

But when I limit the solution to R+

```
Input: Solve[Q == Qconv[T] + Qrad[T], T, PositiveReals]
Ouput: {}
```

Why is this happening ? How do I fix this "error" ?

**Edit**

As explained in comments `Element[Quantity[#, "Kelvins"], PositiveReals]` never returns True.

Is there a way to Take the `QuantityMagnitude[]` for Domain comparation ?

Comment: ``Element[Quantity[605.2454186793566`, "Kelvins"], PositiveReals]`` does not return `True`. It's somewhat ambiguous to look at signs of quantities: if `Quantity[20, "DegreesFahrenheit"]` is positive, is it's corresponding value in Celsius positive too?

Comment: Thanks. I thought because Kelvin is an absolute scale it doesn't have those problems but it seems actually it has them. But can we take the QuantityMagnitud at certain Unit (ex. Celsius, Kelvin, Fahrenheit)?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can recommend you to add the restriction $T>0$ into the Solve parameters, for instance:

```
epsilon = 0.3;
Tinf = Quantity[295.15, "Kelvins"];
Q = Quantity[5000, "Watts"/"Meters"^2];
h = Quantity[10, "Watts"/("Meters"^2*"Kelvins")];
sigma = Quantity[5*10^-8, "Watts"/("Meters"^2*"Kelvins"^4)];

(*Equations*)

Qconv[T_] := h (T - Tinf)
Qrad[T_] := sigma*epsilon*(T^4 - Tinf^4)
Solve[{Q == Qconv[T] + Qrad[T], T > 0}, T, Reals]
```

In this way the solver finds this particular positive real solution only.

Comment: +1 The inequality should contain a `Quantity`, i.e., `Solve[{Q == Qconv[T] + Qrad[T], T > Quantity[0, "Kelvins"]}, T]`. It works with just `0` but if you used any other threshold, it wouldn't work without the `Quantity`